# Docusign Connect push XML post to Custom Listener

Tags: xml, soap, docusignapi

Once an envelope is signed I want to push an XML post containing contents of the envelope to my custom endpoint. I have already configured my listener in Docusigns Connect but i can't figure out where i can view the XML post or test the service if its sending the XML post at all. My retrieving service endpoint uses SOAP.

Where can I test the service once envelope is signed/completed?
Can i look at the contents of the XML post and if so where?
Do I need the SOAP API to enable the communication between docusign and retrieving service endpoint?

I'm fairly new to docusign and web services so pardon me if i am completely off with my strategy and questions.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  SO is not a tutorial or discussion site.  We expect one question per post, and things like _"Where can I test the service once envelope is signed/completed?"_ are off-topic.  Also, these questions can probably be answered using Google and Docusign documentation and support resources.

Answer (score 0):

You would be testing your end to end flow in the DS Demo/Sandbox account, in same account you can configure your listener as DS Admin. Below links will help you in configuring the listener in DS Connect:

[DS Connect Guide](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect-technical-details.htm)

[Connect Technical Info](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect-technical-details.htm)

Now to check logs what XML message is successfully sent from DocuSign, then you can check Logs as per below screenshot[image]

The Failure button will show the failure reason if DS not able to post the Connect XML to your listener